# PHP/jQuery AJAX error response after sending mail

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm writing a mail sender in PHP, and calling it via ajax with jQuery. This is part of my PHP code:

```
    // Send the email.
        if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
            // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
            http_response_code(200);
            echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
        } else {
            // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
            http_response_code(500);
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
        }
```

This is my JS:

```
$(form).submit(function(e) {
        // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
        e.preventDefault();

        // Serialize the form data.
        var formData = $(form).serialize();

        // Submit the form using AJAX.
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: formData

        })
        .done(function(response) {
            // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
            $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
            $(formMessages).addClass('success');

            // Set the message text.
            $(formMessages).text(response);

            // Clear the form.
            $('#nombre').val('');
            $('#email').val('');
            $('#telefono').val('');
            $('#pais').val('');
        })
        .fail(function(data) {
            // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
            $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
            $(formMessages).addClass('success');

            // Set the message text.
            if (data.responseText !== '') {
                $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
            } else {
                $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
            }
        });
    });
```

And the HTML form, just in case:

```
<form id="ajax-contact" method="post" action="mailer.php">
    <ul>
        <li><input name="nombre"  id="nombre" class="inputNombre" placeholder="Nombre" required/></li>
        <li><input name="email" id="email" placeholder="E mail" type="email" class="inputEmail" required/></li>
        <li><input name="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono" class="inputTelefono" id="telefono" required/></li>
        <li><input name="pais" placeholder="País" class="inputPais" id="pais" required /></li>
        <li><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Enviar" class="botonEnviar" id="submit"></input></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

The weird thing here is that, even though the mail is sent, this always goes to the `else` branch and set the 500 code, so when I try to manage the response, I get the wrong one. But I receive the mail, so the `if` is working.

I always get the response code 500, supposedly set for when the mail fails.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You tagged AJAX, but you don't have any javascript code. You should add more code as the piece of code you posted is valid.

Comment: I added more code to clarify, sorry.

Comment: Check PHP error log.

Comment: whats on `mailer.php`?

Comment: Do you know for sure that the 500 error comes from the `else` and not from somewhere else in the code? I would add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the beginning of the file, then call the page directly from the browser (with GET if possible), and see if there is any other error in the file that could be causing this issue

Comment: `error_reporting(-1)` is a handy trick when you don't remember the correct argument.

Comment: I am having a same issue... were you able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `elseif(!)`

```
 if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
                // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
                http_response_code(200);
                echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
            } 

 elseif (!mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
                // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
                http_response_code(500);
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your web hosting's PHP version. You can only set [response codes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) from PHP 5.4. 
Edit: I ran into the exact same problem today. Mail went out, PHP returned with 500 response. I tried to ran the code on another server with PHP 5.5.21 on, and it worked flawlessly.